# How to split one data frame into two after two rows of all NAN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have one data frame containing two entirely different data sets. The data sets are separated by two rows of all NAN values.

I have provided a sample of the data frame below.

```
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
| 13 | NaN                            | NaN         | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | Total Fees | NaN | 653    | NaN |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
| 14 | Expenses\nDate Description ... | NaN         | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN        | NaN | NaN    | NaN |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
| 15 | NaN                            | NaN         | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN        | NaN | NaN    | NaN |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
| 16 | NaN                            | NaN         | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN        | NaN | NaN    | NaN |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
| 17 | Date                           | Description | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN        | NaN | Amount | NaN |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-----+--------+-----+
```

Row 14 is the last row of the first data set, and row 17 is the first row of the second data set.

I would like to end up with two data frames where the first ends at row 14 above and the second starts at row 17 above.

I have tried to split them like this:

```
key = df.isnull().all(1)
dftopdata = df[:key] 
dfbottomdata = df[key:]
```

When I run the code, I get an error saying, "cannot do slice indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers"

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and revise your question accordingly. If you can add a sample dataframe and expected dataframe with the help of the link I suggested , that'd help

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for the comment. I actually don't think the data frame I'm working with is relevant to this particular question. But if you really do, then I can include it.

Comment: XD @anky_91. HarrisonAlley Please provide sample dataframe which can replicate the problem, not the whole dataframe.

Comment: @Vishnudev I was genuinely saying that, after reading your comment I realised that might sound ride too . Thanks :) I removed my comment

Comment: @anky_91 no worries. I am new to this so you're probably right. I added a sample data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture all dataframes by `NaN` rows split

```
is_row_nan = df.isnull().all(1)
is_two_row_nan = (is_row_nan & is_row_nan.shift(1))

dfs = [g for _, g in df.groupby(is_two_row_nan.cumsum())]
```

Sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1, np.nan), (10, 2)))
     0    1
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  1.0  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  1.0
7  1.0  NaN
8  1.0  1.0
9  NaN  1.0
```

Output

```
dfs[0]
     0    1
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN


dfs[1]

     0    1
3  NaN  NaN
4  1.0  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  1.0
7  1.0  NaN
8  1.0  1.0
9  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Updated my answer @anky_91